# Adding data in link table with Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an `Activity` table and a `Client` table. They're linked via table (A Client can have several activities and an activity can have several clients)

I've made a slight change to my project which requires me to add my start_date and end_date from the `Activity` to the link table.(Easier for re-use)

The means the save is going to be somewhat different. I still have my `<%= f.text_field :start_date %>` and enddate formfields. And I think I can keep those(?).

I changed my controller and removed the `:start_date` and `:end_date` from the params method. But I can't figure out how to save them to the `activities_clients` table.

I've tried:

```
@activity = Activity.new(activity_params)
@activity.start_date = params[:start_date]
@activity.end_date = params[:end_date]
```

But that gives me `super: no superclass method start_date=' for #<Activity:0x6041d60>`

Any clue how I can add the start- and enddate to my `activities_clients` table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that what you need essentially is a has-many :through association (see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)

Since you moved `start_date` and `end_date` attributes to the join table, you may no longer invoke them on instances of `Activity` class. This is because the underlying model does not have those columns anymore.

You need to set them on the intermediary instance like so (assuming your model class is called ActivityClient):

```
ActivityClient.create!(
  start_date: ..., 
  end_date: ...,
  client: ...,
  activity: ...)
```

Comment: So I actually need a new model from the linktable?

Comment: If i understand your problem correctly, yes. Please read the documentation from the link i attached and you'll get the idea.

Comment: I've rebuilt it and running a test in my index now. I got all the clients and trying to loop through them asking from `singleclient.activities`. It says: `uninitialized constant Client::Activityclient`. I'm confused.

Comment: Ruby cannot find the Client::Activityclient class. From what i can read you are not using camelcase. Perhaps you have misspelled it? You need to check your code. Anyway, i am updating my answer with a little more information to assist you.

Comment: I forgot the model, haha. It's working now as it should. Still not sure on how to save my activity though. Since it's going through the activities controller?

Comment: In your action method you need to save activity independently from activity_client.

Comment: I want you to be more specific. I'm too new to this to completely understand it. I need to save my @activity in my activity controller. Than what? I still have a param full of client id's when I create an activity. Where do I go with them now? And can I just do `@activity.save` -> `@ac = ActivityClient.new` -> `@ac.activity = @activity` in my activities controller or something?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41855/discussion-between-lefty-and-captaincarl)

Answer (score 0):

In your controller please add

```
@activity.save
```

Comment: Really? Oh I didn't think of that!! No, really... obviously I have a save xD

Comment: @activity.clients.each { |client| client.start_date = @activity.start_date; client.end_date = @activity.start_date;  client.save }

Comment: Nope. `undefined method `start_date' for #<Activity:0x5f93b20>`.

Comment: And with params[:start_date] instead of @activity.start_date: `undefined method start_date=' for #<Client:0x5edcd00>`